# How to share to Twitter AFTER a check-in using Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

Can I share to Twitter/Facebook after a check-in? API for `checkings/add` contains a parameter `broadcast` which allows to sharing to connected Twitter account. But I don't know this information when sending a check-in, sharing to Twitter needs to be optional action after a check-in.

I have tried another `checkings/add` request with different `broadcast` afterwards, but it gets ignored (merged with previous check-in and it's not shared).

I need this for my app [Glasquare](https://github.com/destil/glasquare) (Foursquare for Glass). Implementation of my own Twitter/Facebook sharing would be tricky for me and the users, because it's not easy to authenticate a third party app on Glass (Glass doesn't have any keyboard to type username/password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this functionality isn't currently supported in the Foursquare API. Perhaps have app-level user settings to let them toggle their broadcast option?

Comment: It's tricky because glassware typically doesn't have any settings. But thanks for answer.